# What type of hash function does Python (e.g. 3.6.4, CPython) use?

Tags: python, hash, python-3.6, python-internals

How can I find out what **type** of **hash** function my Python implementation uses for `hash` (the builtin)?

In case it's useful, I'm using `conda` on OS X (3.6.4 CPython)

```
$ hash('foo')
 -5320475886488011515

$ hash('fooo')
7944055534276688058
```

Comment: Apparently you're using a Python version, 3.7.4, that doesn't exist yet

Comment: See the implementation, of course.

Comment: ([CPython source code here](https://github.com/python/cpython))

Comment: @erhesto Definitely a dupe.

Comment: Thanks all. Good catch on the Python version, I corrected it just for completeness. I agree this is a duplicate, sorry couldn't find that on my initial search. Feel free to close as a duplicate.